# Problema com exibição de texto dentro de um <textarea>

Tags: javascript, html5, variáveis, textarea

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Estou fazendo um site HTML5 de edição de texto, nele voce digita algo na caixa de texto e seleciona uma das opções desejadas, 'Uppercase, Lowercase, Bold, Italic, Fixed, Strike, Sub, Sup'.
O problema começa quando tento usar os botões 'Bold, Italic, Fixed, Strike, Sub, Sup', a mensagem retorna na caixa de resposta entre '< b> < /b>, < i> < /i>, < tt> < /tt>, < strike> < /strike>, < sub> < /sub>, < sup> < /sup>' respectivamente, invés de retornar com o efeito de texto. Espero ter sido claro com meu problema, agradeço muito a ajuda!

Segue abaixo o codigo HTML5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ue">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="description" content="site para edição de texto simples">
            <meta name="keywords" content="editar texto, correção de texto, texto, edição">
            <meta name="author" content="@sir_membrive">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Character Transition</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
        </head>

        
        <body>
            <section>
                <h1>Character Transition</h1>
                <div>
                    <p id="paragrafo1">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Uppercase" onclick="maiusculas()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Lowercase" onclick="minusculas()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Bold" onclick="negrito()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Italic" onclick="italico()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Fixed" onclick="fixo()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Strike" onclick="riscado()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Sub" onclick="sub()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Sup" onclick="sup()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Number of Characters" onclick="letras()">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <textarea id="texto" placeholder="Type the text:"></textarea>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <textarea id="res"></textarea>
            </section>


            <footer>
                <p>&copy; Designed by @sir_membrive</p>
            </footer>

            <script src="script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Segue abaixo o codigo Javascript

```
function maiusculas() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.toUpperCase()
}

function minusculas() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.toLowerCase()
}

function negrito() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.bold()
}

function italico() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.italics()
}

function fixo() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.fixed()
}

function riscado() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.strike()
}

function sub() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.sub()
}

function sup() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.sup()
}

function letras() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = `Your text has ${texto.length} characters, including spaces, letters and punctuation.`
}
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 1):

"Não vai funcionar mesmo, vc está tentando renderizar elementos Html em campos que só aceitam string. O método bold() por exemplo, envolve o texto digitado no textarea de cima em tags Html , mas, quando coloca isso de volta em um elemento de entrada que só aceita string (textarea de baixo) isso é convertido para string!" comentário de @LeAndrade

Você pode substituir o textarea por uma `div` com propriedade `resize` e aplicar um `css` para simular um textarea. Dessa forma vai trabalhar conforme esperado.

```js
function maiusculas() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.toUpperCase()
}

function minusculas() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.toLowerCase()
}

function negrito() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.bold()
}

function italico() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.italics()
}

function fixo() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.fixed()
}

function riscado() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.strike()
}

function sub() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.sub()
}

function sup() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = texto.sup()
}

function letras() {
    var texto = document.getElementById('texto').value
    var res = document.getElementById('res')
    res.innerHTML = `Your text has ${texto.length} characters, including spaces, letters and punctuation.`
}
```

```css
#res {
  border: 1px solid #E4E4E4;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 140px;
  height: 20px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ue">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="description" content="site para edição de texto simples">
            <meta name="keywords" content="editar texto, correção de texto, texto, edição">
            <meta name="author" content="@sir_membrive">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Character Transition</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
        </head>

        
        <body>
            <section>
                <h1>Character Transition</h1>
                <div>
                    <p id="paragrafo1">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Uppercase" onclick="maiusculas()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Lowercase" onclick="minusculas()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Bold" onclick="negrito()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Italic" onclick="italico()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Fixed" onclick="fixo()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Strike" onclick="riscado()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Sub" onclick="sub()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Sup" onclick="sup()">
                        <input type="button" class="botao" value="Number of Characters" onclick="letras()">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <textarea id="texto" placeholder="Type the text:"></textarea>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div id="res"></div>
            </section>


            <footer>
                <p>&copy; Designed by @sir_membrive</p>
            </footer>

        </body>
    </html>
```

A propriedade [**resize**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize) CSS define se um elemento é redimensionável e, em caso afirmativo, em quais direções.

A propriedade `resize` pode receber quatro valores possíveis:

- **none**: o controle não poderá ser redimensionado
- **vertical**: o controle poderá ser redimensionado 
      verticalmente
- **horizontal**: o controle poderá ser redimensionado 
      horizontalmente
- **both**: o controle poderá ser redimensionado nas duas 
      dimensões.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Valeu pela menção Leo :) Boa estratégia com o resize da div!